# Accessing WebApi on local website returns 404 error, whereas same deployed on cloud application works fine

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I am facing a weird issue, I have a webapi in my web application "https://myapplicationurl/api/Login/" which worked fine before with local iis deployed website. And after deploying the website to cloud application recently, somehow I am unable to access the webapi "https://myapplicationurl/api/Login/" locally through IIS website.

Any idea with issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue with following handler in web config Web config:

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```